# How to use innerHTML safely?

Tags: javascript, xss

Instead of retyping repeated codes for a side bar in Javascript, I made a sidebar function which is used to populate similar codes for every pages. it looks like this:

```
function addSidebarTemplate(){
      const template = document.createElement('template');
      template.innerHTML = `<aside class="aside-container">
                            <header>
                <a href="."> link here</a>
                <a class="mr-1" href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="mr-1" href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="mr-1" href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                </a>
                 </header>`
       document.querySelector('#sidebar').appendChild(sidebar.content);
```

There are other elements below this code. But none of them requires user's input. I just wonder is this safe to use innerHTML in this case? If not, is there better way to insert the side bar like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no user input is used, then `innerHTML` is fine to use. That being said, if you're doing a lot of this you may want to look into using a UI library like React to help you out.

Comment: I know Flask have jinja syntax and PHP has other way to handle this. I just try to understand the JS in depth. Thank you!